# How do I express today's date in DD/MM/YYYY format using RegEx?

Tags: regex

I'm working with a bespoke application that uses RegEx to validate information. I am creating a function that validates against another field like so:

```
<validationrule key="MandatoryIfToday" type="VRMandatoryFieldIfFieldMatchesRegex" triggerField="PolicyDate" triggerRegEx="**today's date**" mandatoryField="MakeMeMandatory" errorcode="ER_MANDATORY" />
```

To achieve this I simply need to know how to express *today's date* in RegEx format, however I can only find a way of expressing the format DD/MM/YYYY, is it possible to validate *today's date* dynamically using RegEx?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible since regex has no concept of time.

What might work instead is to get today's date as a string in DD/MM/YYYY format, then match the input against it. Or you could parse the input as DD/MM/YYYY then match it against today's date.